# Metrics endpoint for determining server load in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is there a metrics endpoint so that clients can determine how loaded the servers are and throttle/backoff requests accordingly. Currently, the `/prometheus-metrics` endpoint returns too many metrics, most of which are irrelevant. I want a way to only obtain the metrics that I care about, which are `rpcs_in_queue`, `rpc_{in,out}bound_calls_alive`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to filter for Prometheus metrics since [f7438c2](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/f7438c2cc5e119c3f6851b72472f2a742fa9be30) by building a request like the one below:

```
/prometheus-metrics?metrics=<metric-substring1>,<metric-substring2>
```